# Find limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{\sin(x)}-1}{x} = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, limits-without-lhopital

can someone provide me with some hint how to evaluate this limit? 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{\sin(x)}-1}{x} = 0 $$
Unfortunately, I can't use l'hopital's rule 
I was thinking about something like that:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{2^{\sin(x)}-1}{x} =\\\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln(e^{2^{\sin(x)}})-1}{\ln(e^x)} $$ but there I don't see how to continue this way of thinking (of course if it is correct)

Comment: The limit is precisely the definition of $f'(0)$ where $f(x) = 2^{\sin(x)}$. This technically doesn't use L'Hopital's rule! ;-)

Comment: "Unfortunately, I can't use l'hopital's rule" Correction: **Fortunately**, you cannot use LH.

Comment: Just combine $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{a^z-1}{z}=\log a$ with $\lim_{w\to 0}\frac{\sin w}{w}=1$ to get $\color{red}{\log 2}\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

For $\sin x\ne0$

$$\dfrac{2^{\sin x}-1}x=\dfrac{2^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x}\cdot\dfrac{\sin x}x$$

$$\implies\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2^{\sin x}-1}x=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x}\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x$$

Comment: Ok, second part is a theorem which I know, but first part? It is needed to transform it or you mean about theorem  there?

Comment: Why is the limit of the remaining ratio supposed to be easier to determine than the limit of the original ratio?

Comment: The former limit $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{2^{\sin x}-1}{\sin x}$ can be solved by substituting $t=\sin x$. You then get $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{2^t-1}{t}$. Can you proceed?

Comment: @VirtualUser, Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942565/prove-that-lim-x-to-0-dfracax-1x-lna-using-the-definition-of-limit